# Selenium for Python opens chrome tab with "data" rather than specified URL

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

My chromedriver and chrome app are the same up to date version, but the tab still just opens to "data" in the URL bar

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Windows\\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://google.com")
```

Answer (score 0):

Driver instance can be simply:

`driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'path\to\chromedriver.exe')`

*Is chrome and driver at last version?*

The syntax is ok, try to change chromedriver path.

Comment: Yes my versions are updated, i'm not sure what I was doing wrong but it works now